# Hibernate Select Case when empty string

Tags: java, hibernate, string

I am having problems to implement a search in a PostgreSQl table. The table contains columns with empty strng values that causes an error.

Some information from the column design:
Data type: character varying(20)
Default:
Not NULL: No
Primary key: No

My java class annotation for the column:

```
@Column(name = "codeClient")
private String codeClient;
```

This query string works when there is no "empty string" value:

```
SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.id = 765432
```

And my Json returns:

```
[{"id":765432,"nameClient":"JACK SMITH","codeClient":"234567890"}]
```

When I change the query to deal with a empty value:

```
SELECT c.id, c.nameClient, CASE c.codeClient WHEN '' THEN 'nonexistent' else c.codeClient END FROM Client c WHERE c.id = 765432
```

The query works, but the Json result misses de columns descriptions:

```
[[765432,"JACK SMITH","234567890"]]
```

To solve this problem, I change the query to return an object:

```
SELECT new ClientDTO(c.id, c.nameClient, CASE c.codeClient WHEN '' THEN 'nonexistent' else c.codeCliente END) FROM Client c WHERE c.id = 765432
```

But Hibernate can't solve when the result is an empty string:

```
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instatiate class [ClientDTO] from tuple
```

I've tried to use JPA CriteriaBuilder. It works on simple querys, but due to the complexity, I could not implement a query that I need.

I can't change de database design and I need the Json result.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: Also I think there might be a problem with your JSON marshaller. You should instruct it to include the empty values as well. Probably your second Hibernate query works fine but your JSON marshaller doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `CASE c.codeClient WHEN '' THEN 'nonexistent' else c.codeCliente END` logic in the DTO:

```
public ClientDTO(){
...
    this.codeClient = ("".equals(codeClient)) ? "nonexistent" : c.codeClient;
...
}
```

and the leave the query as simple as possible:

```
SELECT new ClientDTO(c.id, c.nameClient, c.codeClient) FROM Client c WHERE c.id = 765432
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate ClientDTO probably because that class is not mapped in persistence.xml. You may change 'new ClientDTO()' to 'new Client()'.

Comment: You don't have to map the DTO, in fact you can pass any class to the SELECT clause as long as its constructor is appropriate for the values selected.